# A cross-origin error was thrown problem with Codesandbox.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, codesandbox

I have "A cross-origin error was thrown" Error in Codesanbox.io when i tried to execute this code.
please what can i do to go over ?
I'm using Create-react-app with codesanbox.io

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    customer: [
      { id: 1, name: "Leon" },
      { id: 1, name: "Lea" },
      { id: 1, name: "Vanelle" }
    ]
  };
  render() {
    const title = "Customer list";
    const elements = this.state.customer.map();
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            Philippe <button>X</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Add a customer" />
          <button>Confirm</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Link to the codebox sample please?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/async-morning-0lti3?codemirror=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `render` function should `map` through each of the `customer` found in the state. Just calling `this.state.customer.map()` throws an error which it seems is not handled properly by `codesandbox`.

Try this for your render:

```
render() {
    const title = "Customer list";
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{title}</h1>

        <ul>
        {
          this.state.customer.map(c => (
            <li key={c.id}>
             {c.name} <button>X</button>
            </li>
          ))
        }
        </ul>
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Add a customer" />
          <button>Confirm</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it's codesandbox's fault? 
Did you read here: https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/667

Normally, cross-origin error is something you can control in the backend instead of frontend (browser). I suspect that you have called some API in the code that you shouldn't have the permission to call in the browser. CORS is a whole topic to read. To truly understand, I think you should spend some time to digest it.